# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Macbook Air - Keyboad not working after mtrack install

Tags: xorg, touchpad, macbook-air

I have installed 16.04 LTS on my macbook air using refind no problems and have run apt-get upgrade and update no problem. However the trackpad is very sketchy, so i did some reading on the web and ended up installing mtrack as a potential fix to the trackpad issues. After installing and rebooting, i now have no keyboard working. to login i can use the on screen keyboard, but after logging in i am left with no keyboard at all. Is there a way to get the keyboard working again without having to reinstall again? Also any fix to the sketchy track pad (mtrack didn't work).
TIA

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently on an older MacBook Pro.  It looks like the problem happens because installing the mtrack package automatically removes a bunch of other input packages.  I fixed it by using the onscreen keyboard to run

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

then rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I think mtrack is a pain to install correctly for some reason, and has the potential to break one's system. Anyway, the same thing happened with my Macbook Air running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I was unable to get the onscreen keyboard because my cursor wasn't responding along with the keyboard. In the Grub menu at boot, I selected the "upstart" option and after logging in through the command line, installed

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev